# Get data by dll - async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dll, async-await

i had a c# application to get data from azure, but i need a dll to do this and i have big problem with async task and return data.

My dll code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static string connectionString = "XXXX";
        private static string d2cEndpoint = "messages/events";
        private static EventHubClient eventHubClient;

        public async static Task<string> read()
        {
        eventHubClient = EventHubClient.
           CreateFromConnectionString(
              connectionString, d2cEndpoint);

        var d2cPartitions = eventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformation().PartitionIds;

        // wait for data from async task
        string task = await ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(d2cPartitions[0]);

        // return data from DLL
        return task;
        }

        private async static Task<string> ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(string partition)
        {
            var eventHubReceiver = eventHubClient.
                  GetDefaultConsumerGroup().
                    CreateReceiver(partition, DateTime.UtcNow);

            EventData eventData = await eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync();

            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is get data from this dll - no error, but no data too (i think no wait to get data from cloud)

```
var result = Program.read();

MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(result), "Some title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
return true;
```

What is wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: "VS show many error" - How about to show  this errors in your question?

Comment: Your `read` method **must** be async if you use await inside it: `public async Task<string> read()`

Comment: @FedericoDipuma yes after change method to async dll compile correct but still i cant get data via this dll (no errors, but no data too) - details in edited question

Comment: `var result = Program.Read();` - this will return a task, not the data, only when this task completes will you have the data. This what is wrong.

Comment: `async`/`await` must be used on the entire call stack. You cannot have an `async` method without calling `await` on it (or by using `.Result` or `.Wait()` on the returned task, **but** be aware that this is a really bad practice). I think you need to [fully understand the keyword usage before using it](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how can i wait for complete task and get returned data?

Comment: `var data = await Program.Read();` ? Since you've already used async and await somewhere else I would think you should already know this.

Comment: Why not install fiddler and see what the http request is returning ? That would be a good place to start.